# Could be dangerous or useful to use instance methods without instantiating any object?

Tags: python, class, oop, memory-management, instantiation

Well, I've recently started studying Python, but I just found that, because of how the language works, I can do something that I don't know what kind of consecuences could it have.

Here is an example:

```
class crazyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Crazy Class"  # Irrelevant, just to have something

    def madnessUnleashed(self):
        print("WAJALAKAMAKACHAKA!")

# Now I want to use madnessUnleashed
# But I don't want to instantiate any object.

crazyClass.madnessUnleashed(crazyClass())  # Damn, I'm instantiating an object, but is it temporary or what?
```

I'm not sure if this can stay as a mere curiosity, or if this is something that could be useful, or if this can generate memory leaks...

Any answer would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This alone does not lead to memory leaks because of python's garbage collection (citation needed). If you do open e.g. a filehandle in the method of the class without ever closing it, that's another story...

Comment: @Dschoni opening a file handle won't create any memory leaks either. But it is definitely something you need to watch out for since you can get other problems when doing this. For example not being able to open the file in a different program as long as your program is running. I'm sure you meant this, just wanted to point this out to avoid any confusion

Comment: @TimWoocker Jepp ;)

Comment: It's not a "curiosity". See the answers below about the `staticmethod` decorator. The usual question you face is "should I make this a staticmethod or simply extract the method into a common function outside any class?" Is the function really so close related to the class to justify being a class method?

Answer (score 2):

It won't generate any memory leaks. Starting from the line where you create the object, things happen in this order:

1. a new instance of the class `crazyClass` is created
2. `madnessUnleashed` is being called as a static method so `self` is in this case the object created before.
3. python's garbage collector checks if the object is still referenced (it's not) and removes it from memory

So basically nothing special happening here.
You can read more about the garbage collector here: https://rushter.com/blog/python-garbage-collector/

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure. The first thing I thought was about ruby's temporary instances... But i'm not sure if this could be considered similar. Also, do you think that it's strictly correct to say "static way"? You can't actually call the method without an instance, and it acts only on the current instance (not here, because it does nothing, but you know what I mean).

Comment: @Inot `self` is just a placeholder for the instance if you are using it as a method. When calling it from the class, you can use anything as an argument. I'd say that you are calling it statically then. It's not really a static method, you can add the `@staticmethod` decorator to really make it static however. Just keep in mind that it's not good practise to call a method from the class itself and you should avoid it as long as you can.

Comment: I didn't noticed that you could use anything as an argument... This is so broken. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) - it doesn't require a class instance, so can be called with just the class.

> *A static method can be called either on the class (such as  `C.f()`) or on an instance (such as `C().f()`).*

Use it as a decorator on the method:

```
class crazyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Crazy Class"

    @staticmethod
    def madnessUnleashed():  # there's no `self`
        print("WAJALAKAMAKACHAKA!")


crazyClass.madnessUnleashed()  # no instance created
```

---

In your example with a normal method in a class, `crazyClass.madnessUnleashed(crazyClass())` does in fact create an instance of the class, which could be seen as an overhead. It could have a higher performance impact if instantiating it involves file creation, network requests, DB connections, etc. Or if you're using them in a loop in the millions, creating those instances repeatedly will affect performance.

**As to your question about memory leaks:** once the method has finished executing, Python's garbage collector will delete the instance (though not immediately after), so it's not a memory *leak*.

Comment: Thanks, I've been reading about "staticmethod" and "classmethod", and it seems that "classmethod" has a more similar behavior to the 'static' concept. Just because "staticmethod" doesn't allow to act over the class' variables, and it makes basically a regular function within a namespace...